pgbouncer trust authentication failed
I am trying to create a spring application that connects to a postgresql database. The application works fine when connecting to the db directly but when I try to connect to it through pgbouncer the trust authenication fails. I want to connect to pgbouncer for load balancing purposes.
For now everything is running on localhost. My application attempts to connect to pgbouncer but I get the following error:
LOG C-0x5583ca3d3490: (nodb)/(nouser)@127.0.0.1:39042 no such user: postgres
LOG C-0x5583ca3d3490: (nodb)/postgres@127.0.0.1:39042 login attempt: db=Test69 user=postgres tls=no
LOG C-0x5583ca3d3490: (nodb)/postgres@127.0.0.1:39042 closing because: "trust" authentication failed (age=0s)
WARNING C-0x5583ca3d3490: (nodb)/postgres@127.0.0.1:39042 pooler error: "trust" authentication failed

From what I understand trust authentication should just let anyone connect but for some reason it fails

Trust authentication still requires the specified user to exist.  In your case, the specified user does not exist (according to pgbouncer, so presumably it is not in the "user_list.txt" or whatever it is called in your config.)

Hello, I have added the users in the uselist.txt file and now I get connection failed so I guess I am on the right path
